# decide glm is better

Tags: r, multiple-regression

This is a newbie question.

I want to know how to determine that one model is better than another.

```
mydata <- read.csv("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv")
mydata$rank = factor(mydata$rank)
logit.gre = glm(admit~gre, data=mydata)
logit.gpa = glm(admit~gpa, data=mydata)
logit.rank = glm(admit~rank, data=mydata)
```

I call summary() of each logit and I got the following results

```
Call:
glm(formula = admit ~ gre, data = mydata)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-0.4755  -0.3415  -0.2522   0.5989   0.8966  

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -0.1198407  0.1190510  -1.007 0.314722    
gre          0.0007442  0.0001988   3.744 0.000208 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 0.2103746)

    Null deviance: 86.677  on 399  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 83.729  on 398  degrees of freedom
AIC: 515.6

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 2
```

---

```
Call:
glm(formula = admit ~ gpa, data = mydata)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-0.4507  -0.3312  -0.2531   0.5908   0.8942  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -0.42238    0.20606  -2.050 0.041037 *  
gpa          0.21826    0.06041   3.613 0.000341 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 0.210866)

    Null deviance: 86.677  on 399  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 83.925  on 398  degrees of freedom
AIC: 516.53

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 2
```

---

```
Call:
glm(formula = admit ~ rank, data = mydata)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-0.5410  -0.3576  -0.2314   0.4590   0.8209  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.54098    0.05798   9.330  < 2e-16 ***
rank2       -0.18337    0.06870  -2.669  0.00792 ** 
rank3       -0.30958    0.07111  -4.354 1.71e-05 ***
rank4       -0.36188    0.08014  -4.516 8.34e-06 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 0.2050699)

    Null deviance: 86.677  on 399  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 81.208  on 396  degrees of freedom
AIC: 507.37

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 2
```

Is it possible to tell that one model is better than another based on the summary output?

Which values in summary are important for comparing models?

Comment: Your code is fitting a normal linear model, not logistic regression.

Comment: Please define "better". If you are interested in predicting, you should validate the model or at least cross-validate.

Comment: @Roland As a newbie it's not easy to ask a correct question. But suppose that there is correlation between gre and gpa in my dataset. So I want to choose only one column. Is there a way to know which one is better?

Comment: @OlegPavliv What is your goal? Do you want to predict or are you interested in statistical inference?

Comment: @Roland I want to know if the output from summary() could help me to decide which model is better is some sense.

Comment: @OlegPavliv As long as you don't define "in some sense" your question can't be answered. You can of course compare the residual deviance, but the model fitting the data most closely is not "best"  for all purposes.

Comment: Do you really have to choose one of these three models?  Ordinarily one would, at the very minimum, examine a model in which all three regressors are simultaneously included, due to the likelihood that collectively they will perform better than picking any individual regressor.